# How to get Text Area in WordPress posts section?

Tags: php, wordpress, textarea, field, posts

I need to change this code to implement "More info" field as a text field in my WordPress post section.

The "More info" field looks like this:

[image: More info]

I use `smartmetabox`. It has 2 files:

`textarea.php`:

```
<textarea name="<?php echo $id?>" id="<?php echo $id?>" rows="5" cols="100" class="custom"><?php echo $value?></textarea>
```

`text.php`:

```
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $id?>" id="<?php echo $id?>" value="<?php echo $value?>" class="regular-text" />
```

And `my_file.php` code is:

```
<?php

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );

function cd_meta_box_add()

{

add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', __('Information', 'addict'), 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );

}

function cd_meta_box_cb( $post )

{

$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );


$creteria_1_text = isset( $values['creteria_1_text'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['creteria_1_text'][0] ) : '';


$check = isset( $values['my_meta_box_check'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['my_meta_box_check'][0] ) : '';

wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );

?>


<p>

<label for="creteria_1_text"><b><?php _e("More info, 'addict') ?></b></label>

<input style="width:85%" type="text" name="creteria_1_text" id="creteria_1_text" value="<?php echo $creteria_1_text; ?>" />
</p>



<?php

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );

function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )

{

// Bail if we're doing an auto save

if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

// if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail

if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

// if our current user can't edit this post, bail

if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

// now we can actually save the data

$allowed = array(

'a' => array( // on allow a tags

'href' => array() // and those anchords can only have href attribute

)

);

// Probably a good idea to make sure your data is set

if( isset( $_POST['creteria_1_text'] ) )

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'creteria_1_text', wp_kses( $_POST['creteria_1_text'], $allowed ) );

}

// function for show rating content

//$key_1_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_meta_box_text', true);

?>
```

Comment: After some digging i found that i should replace this code: 

`<input style="width:85%" type="text" name="creteria_1_text" id="creteria_1_text" value="<?php echo $creteria_1_text; ?>`

To:

`<textarea name="creteria_1_text" id="creteria_1_text" rows="5" cols="100" class="custom"><?php echo $creteria_1_text; ?></textarea>` 

 But all text goes in one line. How to print text with format? for ex:  a few sentece with space between them?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging i found that i should replace this code:

```
<input style="width:85%" type="text" name="creteria_1_text" id="creteria_1_text" value="<?php echo $creteria_1_text; ?>
```

To:

```
<textarea name="creteria_1_text" id="creteria_1_text" rows="5" cols="100" class="custom"><?php echo $creteria_1_text; ?></textarea>
```